# Warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am trying to return a character array but I am getting the error shown above. I am new to programming so I dont know much. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
int* printParty(int party)
{
    char* partyArr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);

    switch (party)
    {
            case 1:
                    strncpy(partyArr, "Constitution", 15);
                    break;
            case 2:
                    strncpy(partyArr, "Democrat", 15);;
                    break;
            case 3:
                    strncpy(partyArr, "Green", 15);
                    break;
            case 4:
                    strncpy(partyArr,"Libertarian", 15);
                    break;
            case 5:
                    strncpy(partyArr, "Republican", 15);
                    break;
            default:
                    printf("Not a valid input.");
    }
return partyArr;
}
```

Comment: change return type to `char*` instead of `int*`

Comment: OT: regarding: `char* partyArr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);`  1) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression.  2) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest removing the cast.

Comment: The posted code has the logic problem that if the `default` case is executed, then the returned value is garbage.  I.E. What ever happened to be in the allocated heap memory.  Suggest setting the array pointed to by `partyArr` to `unknown`